# Gemfire configuration issues

Tags: java, spring, exception, gemfire, spring-data-gemfire

I have an xml config file for setting up gemfire as below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:gfe="http://www.springframework.org/schema/gemfire"
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/gemfire http://www.springframework.org/schema/gemfire/spring-gemfire.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <context:component-scan
        base-package="com.mycompany.data.testcache" />
    <context:annotation-config />

    <util:properties id="props" location="classpath:test-cache.properties">
        <prop key="log-level">info</prop>
    </util:properties>

    <gfe:cache id="gemfire-cache" properties-ref="props" />

    <gfe:local-region id="region1">
        <gfe:cache-listener ref="listener" />
    </gfe:local-region>

    <bean id="listener"
        class="com.mycompany.data.TestLoggingCacheListener" />
</beans>
```

When I try to load this config file, I see the below exception..

> org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
>   Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'region1': Cannot resolve reference to
>   bean 'gemfireCache' while setting bean property 'cache'; nested
>   exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
>   bean named 'gemfireCache' is defined  at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:328)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:106)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1360)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1118)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:567)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:913)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:464)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:103)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:1)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.support.DelegatingSmartContextLoader.loadContext(DelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:228)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.TestContext.loadApplicationContext(TestContext.java:124)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.TestContext.getApplicationContext(TestContext.java:148)
>     ... 24 more Caused by:
>
> org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
>   bean named 'gemfireCache' is defined  at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanDefinition(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:529)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getMergedLocalBeanDefinition(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1095)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:277)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:322)
>     ... 41 more

When I remove the id attribute from

```
<gfe:cache id="gemfire-cache" properties-ref="props" />
```

and just give

```
<gfe:cache properties-ref="props" />
```

it works fine. When I specify id attribute it throws t
Can any one please help me in

Comment: Can anyone answer the below link

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13921971/values-are-not-being-populated-into-gemfire-cache

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use an id attribute with gfe:cache element, then you have to use cache-ref attribute to reference it:

```
<gfe:cache id="gemfire-cache" properties-ref="props" />

<gfe:local-region id="region1" cache-ref="gemfire-cache">
    <gfe:cache-listener ref="listener" />
</gfe:local-region>
```

Otherwise, a default id is used, which is "gemfireCache" (that is why you are seeing "gemfireCache" in the error message).

Comment: Hi Zulich can you answer my another question posted at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13921971/values-are-not-being-populated-into-gemfire-cache