# Values are not being populated into gemfire cache

Tags: java, spring, gemfire, spring-data-gemfire

I have 2 xml config files as below

**app-context.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:gfe="http://www.springframework.org/schema/gemfire" xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/gemfire http://www.springframework.org/schema/gemfire/spring-gemfire.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd">


    <context:component-scan
        base-package="com.mycompany.data.testcache" />
    <context:annotation-config />

    <import resource="test-cache.xml" />

    <bean id="testCache" class="org.springframework.data.gemfire.GemfireTemplate">
        <property name="region" ref="region1" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

**test-cache.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:gfe="http://www.springframework.org/schema/gemfire"
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/gemfire http://www.springframework.org/schema/gemfire/spring-gemfire.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <context:component-scan
        base-package="com.mycompany.data.testcache" />
    <context:annotation-config />

    <util:properties id="props" location="classpath:test-cache.properties">
        <prop key="log-level">info</prop>
    </util:properties>

    <gfe:cache id="gemfire-cache" properties-ref="props" />

    <gfe:local-region id="region1" cache-ref="gemfire-cache">
        <gfe:cache-listener ref="listener" />
    </gfe:local-region>

    <bean id="listener"
        class="com.mycompany.data.TestLoggingCacheListener" />
</beans>
```

and I have a test class called **TestCache.java**

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "classpath:app-context.xml" })
public class TestCache {

    @Autowired
    GemfireTemplate testCache;

    @Test
    public void testgetSomeValues() {

        HashMap<String, String> map1 = retrieveSomeValues();

        HashMap<String, String> map2 = retrieveSomeValues();

        assertEquals(Map1, Map2);
    }

    @Cacheable(value = "testCache")
    public HashMap<String, String> retrieveSomeValues() {

        HashMap<String, String> obj = new HashMap<String, String>();
        obj.put("600", "Auto");
        obj.put("601", "Life");

        return obj;
    }

}
```

But I see nothing is actually being cached into the region. for both the method calls to retrieveSomeValues() method, the method is actually being executed instead of retrieving the values from the cache.

Can I know what is wrong in the above test class. Can I know how can I use the @Cacheable to cache the values for the able retriveSomeValues() method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need Spring Framework's cache support in order to use @Cacheable. There is a Spring GemFire quickstart example that shows how to use GemFire with @Cacheable annotation at:

https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-gemfire-examples/tree/master/quickstart/spring-cache

You'll find everything you need there: the xml configuration for the app, cache, gemfire, and code that uses the annotation.